# Jquery not displaying result of loop over data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Jquery function that loops over a class item and gets the amount of list items based on the attribute `data-search-position`. When the alert is triggered it displays the correct amount, but when I try to bind the result to a div it does not work?

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RS41/rp35fmq8/2/)

```js
/*

var colorCount = $('#result-item-1 .item-colours-result ul li');

if (colorCount.length > 0)  {
   $('.numberOfColours').html(colorCount.length + '&nbsp;' + 'Colours');
}

else {
   $('.numberOfColours').hide();
}

*/

$('.search').each(function(index,item){
  var colorCount = $(item).find('.item-colours-result ul li').length;
  //alert(item.id+':'+colorCount)
  $(item).attr('data-search-position',colorCount)
  $("#numberOfColours").html(colorCount + '&nbsp;' + 'Colours');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result-item-1" class="search" data-search-position="1" style="width: 50%;">
<div class='item-colours-result'>
<ul class=""><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul>
</div>
</div>

<div id="numberOfColours">Test</div>


<div id="result-item-2" class="search" data-search-position="2" style="width: 50%;">
<div class='item-colours-result'>
<ul class=""><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li></ul>
</div>
</div>

<div id="numberOfColours">Test</div>


<div id="result-item-3" class="search" data-search-position="3" style="width: 50%;">
<div class='item-colours-result'>
<ul class=""><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li></ul>
</div>
</div>

<div id="numberOfColours">Test</div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid since it has multiple id's of `id="numberOfColours"`, an id on an element MUST be unique within a document tree https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute  Therefore, I have voted to close as this is a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use same id for multiple elements, use class instead.
See below code, where i have used class and used `.next()` to get the div to display number of colors

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.search').each(function(index,item){
  var colorCount = $(item).find('.item-colours-result ul li').length;
  //alert(item.id+':'+colorCount)
  $(item).attr('data-search-position',colorCount)
  $(this).next(".numberOfColours").html(colorCount + '&nbsp;' + 'Colours');
})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result-item-1" class="search" data-search-position="1" style="width: 50%;">
<div class='item-colours-result'>
<ul class=""><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul>
</div>
</div>

<div class="numberOfColours">Test</div>


<div id="result-item-2" class="search" data-search-position="2" style="width: 50%;">
<div class='item-colours-result'>
<ul class=""><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li></ul>
</div>
</div>

<div class="numberOfColours">Test</div>


<div id="result-item-3" class="search" data-search-position="3" style="width: 50%;">
<div class='item-colours-result'>
<ul class=""><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li></ul>
</div>
</div>

<div class="numberOfColours">Test</div>
```

Comment: Although that works in your code snippet, It is not working for me? Is there anything that could stop that working?

Comment: you need to change id to class for numberOfColours div

Comment: you need to ensure that DOM is loaded fully before applying jquery hence i put the jquery code inside `$(document).ready`. I have updated your jsfiddle with my code and it is working - https://jsfiddle.net/0nzL6jq8/